# Code::Blocks 13.12 gdb cannot open file error -

Tags: gdb

I am running Code::Blocks 13.12 on Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit machine. I am using Cygwin toolset.

I have searched the internet and found that the technique described for fixing this error -

Add to registry the following:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Cygwin\mounts v2]
    "cygdrive prefix"="/cygdrive"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Cygwin\mounts v2]
     "cygdrive prefix"="/cygdrive"
```

does not work in my case.

Does anyone have any other ideas? I can always just run gdb from command line and that does work but sort of defeats the purpose of using an IDE.

Comment: Umm... what is "this error"?

Comment: The error is Code::Blocks is not able to open source file when attempting to run the debugger. See http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=19622.0

Comment: The only remedies I have discovered have to do with modifying the registry as describe above. It appears that some folks were successful with the registry fix, alas I cannot say the same for me....

I decided to install Code::Blocks with the MinGW configuration and now all is well with the debugger. Cygwin would have been my preferred environment but for my simple purposes at this point MinGW is sufficient for now.